# Populate location property in User Profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-profile-property

The Office Location (SPS-Location) property in user Profile is being fetched from termset which is blank in my case. I want AAD property Office to be populated in this user profile proerty. I tried creating a new property in SP Online but unable to map it to office. Any pointers in populating the existing property or create a new office location property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to populate the TermSet (or have users populate their own profile) and edit your user's profile with this information. You cannot change the mapping. The `Office` value is populated from the Azure AD attribute `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` which you may consider populating. This also has an identically named attribute in Active Directory should you be using AAD Connect.

[Information about user profile synchronization in SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3168272/information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-sharepoint-online)

Comment: The `office` field is getting populated with `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` but not the `Office Location`. Can I create a new property and get it synced?

Comment: Correct, `Office Location` is not synchronized with any attribute; it is a TermSet which you can populate with values and have users select them, or edit their profiles yourself. There is no automatic population of any profile properties outside of the list in the link I provided. You would need to use a solution such as https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UserProfiles.Sync in order to populate from Active Directory on-prem to SPO directly.